# c# XML read: read of nodes with same node name

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I have the below XML with more "string" nodes (number of string nodes are defined by a tool - how many languages are added to it)
I used `system.xml` to save each node into a string like with the below code:

Is there an option to save each "string"'s `InnerText` to an array?
I also tried the below code (for loop) but don't know how to define the number of loops (stringnumber).
Any advice would be appreciated.

```
valid = TBElement.GetElementsByTagName("Valid")[0].InnerText;

for (int b = 0; b == stringnumber; b++)
{
    languages[b] = TBElement.GetElementsByTagName("Languages/string")[0].InnerText;
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<ArrayOfGlobalInfo>
 <GlobalInfo>
  <NumberOfEntries>2</NumberOfEntries>
  <LanguageNewDefaultOptions />
  <Languages>
    <string>eng</string>
    <string>ger</string>
    <string>ita</string>
    <string>fre</string>
  </Languages>
  <Valid>true</Valid>
 </GlobalInfo>
</ArrayOfGlobalInfo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it with XML Linq in one instruction

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string[] languages = doc.Descendants("string").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of loops can be found from the below

```
TBElement.GetElementsByTagName("Languages/string").Count()
```

just store it in a variable and use it in the loop condition

```
 var stringnumber = TBElement.GetElementsByTagName("Languages/string").Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("YourXMLFile");
XmlNodeList elemList = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("string");
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerText);
        }
```

another solution is this way:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Your file path");
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ArrayOfGlobalInfo/GlobalInfo/Languages/string");

foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
                {
//Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var stringElements = TBElement.GetElementsByTagName("Languages/string");
List<string> languages = new List<string>();

foreach (var element in stringElements)
    languages.Add(element.InnerText);
```

If you prefer arrays:

```
var stringElements = TBElement.GetElementsByTagName("Languages/string");
string[] languages = new string[stringElements.Count];

for (int i = 0; i != stringElements.Count; ++i)
    languages[i] = stringElements[i].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is to do this:

```
xmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.InnerText).ToArray();
```

...Where xmlNodeList is the result of your successfully evaluated XPath expression in GetElementsByTagName().

But you might consider:

- Whether you might be better of using XDocument instead of XmlDocument
- Whether you really need an array, since XmlNodeList already has a .Count property

This illustrates a few of your options:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace _43387906
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string _xml = "<ArrayOfGlobalInfo>\r\n <GlobalInfo>\r\n  <NumberOfEntries>2</NumberOfEntries>\r\n  <LanguageNewDefaultOptions />\r\n  <Languages>\r\n    <string>eng</string>\r\n    <string>ger</string>\r\n    <string>ita</string>\r\n    <string>fre</string>\r\n  </Languages>\r\n  <Valid>true</Valid>\r\n </GlobalInfo>\r\n</ArrayOfGlobalInfo>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(_xml);
                UseXDocumentVerbose(xDocument);
                UseXDocumentShorter(xDocument);

                var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(_xml);

                UseXmlDocument(xmlDocument);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void UseXmlDocument(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
        {
            var languages = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("ArrayOfGlobalInfo/GlobalInfo/Languages/string");

            //You can use languages.Count without converting to an array
            for (int i = 0; i < languages.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(languages[i].InnerText);
            }

            //The trick is to use Cast<T>() and ToArray()
            var languagesArray = languages.Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.InnerText).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < languagesArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(languagesArray[i]);
            }
        }

        private static void UseXDocumentShorter(XDocument xDocument)
        {
            if (xDocument.Root.Name != "ArrayOfGlobalInfo")
                throw new Exception("Root isn't ArrayOfGlobalInfo");

            var languages = xDocument.Root
                                     .Elements("GlobalInfo")
                                     .SelectMany(i => i.Elements("Languages"))
                                     .SelectMany(l => l.Elements("string"))
                                     .Select(s => s.Value).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                                     .ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < languages.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(languages[i]);
            }
        }

        private static void UseXDocumentVerbose(XDocument xDocument)
        {
            if (xDocument.Root.Name != "ArrayOfGlobalInfo")
                throw new Exception("Root isn't ArrayOfGlobalInfo");

            var globalInfoElements = xDocument.Root.Elements("GlobalInfo");

            var languageElements = globalInfoElements.SelectMany(i => i.Elements("Languages"));

            var languages = languageElements.SelectMany(l => l.Elements("string")).Select(s => s.Value).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < languages.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(languages[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```